# How would I add networked multiplayer support to an iPhone game?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am looking to extend an iPhone game by adding support for networked multiplayer capabilities (preferably over WiFi).  How would you suggest I add this functionality to this application?

Comment: Probably because it is ambiguous, and sounds like you could/should Google it.

Comment: Also probably due to the fact that adding support for more than one player is completely dependent on the specific game mechanics (which you did not specify).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Game Kit can be used to add match making and network communications to your game.

Start with the [Game Kit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304) which has step-by-step instructions for many scenarios and lots of sample code.